# Count objects (in an array) having timestamps of last few days, weeks and months from 'current time'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, momentjs, lodash

I have an array of objects with timestamps as a property:

#### Sample Input:

```js
const data = [
  {
    _id: "602102db3acc4515d4b2f687",
    createdDt: "2021-02-08T09:22:35.000Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "6021024da706a260d8932da2",
    createdDt: "2021-02-08T09:20:13.000Z",
  },
  // ...
  // ...
  {
    _id: "6020fd863acc4515d4b2f685",
    createdDt: "2021-02-08T08:59:50.000Z",
  },
];
```

Now starting from the **current date**, I need **counts** of total objects with timestamps of *this day*, *previous day* and so on (count can be zero if there is no entry in the previous day).

In the same way, I need **counts** for this day, previous day and so on, also same with weeks and months.

For example, the output I am expecting could be like:

#### Sample Output:

```js
const result = {
  days: [0, 0, 5, 10, ...],
  weeks: [15, 5, 8, 0, ...],
  months: [30, 42, 33, 23, ...]
}
```

I am using ES6, Lodash and moment.js. This is for basic graphical representation.

---

#### Update:

This is the code I wrote, can someone suggest a simpler solution?

#### My current solution:

```js
for (var i = 0, k = 1; i < 365; i++, k++) {
  let dt = moment().subtract(i, "days");
  let td = moment().subtract(k, "days");
  builddays.push(0);
  for (var j = 0; j < drivers.length; j++) {
    let ddt = new Date(drivers[j].createdDt);
    if (moment(ddt).isBetween(td, dt)) builddays[i] = drivers[j].count;
  }
}

var weeksbifurcate = builddays.reduce((resultArray, item, index) => {
  const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index / 7);

  if (!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
    resultArray[chunkIndex] = [];
  }

  resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item);

  return resultArray;
}, []);

var monthsbifurcate = builddays.reduce((resultArray, item, index) => {
  const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index / 30);

  if (!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
    resultArray[chunkIndex] = [];
  }

  resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item);

  return resultArray;
}, []);

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  days.push(builddays[i]);
  weeks.push(weeksbifurcate[i].reduce(getSum, 0));
  months.push(monthsbifurcate[i].reduce(getSum, 0));
}
```

Comment: So use reduce... loop over and change createdDt into a Date. Figure out time difference (date - now) and than figure out what bucket it needs to be in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [moment # diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to find indices, i.e. `dayIndex`, `weekIndex`, `monthIndex` and put or increment the right `index` in corresponding `array` in `result` object:

```js
const solve = (data) => {
  const result = {
    days: [],
    weeks: [],
    months: [],
  };
  data.forEach((item) => {
    const today = moment();
    const createdDt = moment(item.createdDt);

    const dayIndex = today.diff(createdDt, "days");
    const weekIndex = today.diff(createdDt, "weeks");
    const monthIndex = today.diff(createdDt, "months");

    result.days[dayIndex] = (result.days[dayIndex] || 0) + 1;
    result.weeks[weekIndex] = (result.weeks[weekIndex] || 0) + 1;
    result.months[monthIndex] = (result.months[monthIndex] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return result;
};

const data = [
  {createdDt: "2021-03-03T00:00:00.000Z",},
  {createdDt: "2021-03-03T00:00:00.000Z",},
  {createdDt: "2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",},
  {createdDt: "2021-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",},
  {createdDt: "2021-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",},
  {createdDt: "2021-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",},
  {createdDt: "2021-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",},
  {createdDt: "2021-02-24T00:00:00.000Z",},
  {createdDt: "2021-02-23T00:00:00.000Z",},
];

console.log(solve(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

There might be few `undefined` values in the result, but there is no need to set it to `0` as it can be considered as `0` wherever you are going to show/use it.